# How to change the Login Shell on Mac OS X from bash to zsh?

Tags: macos, shell

I'm trying to change the Login Shell of Mac OS X from `bash` to `zsh`. I see [it is possible in Mac OS X Leopard](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071025221744166), but for OS X Lion I can't find a way. I really hope it is possible to change the Login shell from bash to something else. I am not exactly sure where to look for.

Comment: After changing shell to zsh, I still had to launch zsh manually. Logging out didn't help. I then changed zsh to the upmost login shell. Logged out and there it was.

Comment: If nothing else, you can always modify the .bashrc to find and exec zsh.  `if [ -x /usr/local/bin/zsh ] ; then exec /usr/local/bin/zsh fi`.  Hint, when modifying shell startup scripts, make sure to keep a shell running and start up a new one in another window - if you break it you still have an easy place to fix it.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can change user shell by the following command:

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

<sup>Note: To change it for a non-standard shell, make sure its path has been added to `/etc/shells` file.</sup>

Comment: I installed a newer version of zsh with Homebrew, which put zsh in `/usr/local/bin/zsh`. Unfortunately, chsh doesn't allow this, saying `chsh: /usr/local/bin/zsh: non-standard shell`. Daniel Beck's answer is a suitable solution in this case.

Comment: If you are getting problems with non-standard shells, I think you should be able to add `/usr/local/bin/zsh` to `/etc/shells` and it should solve that problem.

Comment: The homebrew zsh install info does actually recommend you to add it to /etc/shells:  
`==> Caveats
To use this build of Zsh as your login shell, add it to /etc/shells.`

Comment: Doesn't work sometimes. @frank's answer ensures it though

Comment: /etc/shells is a read only file? doesn't let me edit it.

Comment: @Awesome_girl By default, `/etc/shells` is owned, and only writable by, root (the superuser). You could, for example, use `sudo vi /etc/shells` to use `sudo` (**s**uper **u**ser **do**) to run the `vi` editor to edit `/etc/shells`. I just tested on my system and confirmed that it is NOT protected by System Integrity Protection, so you should be able to edit it as root without jumping through hoops to disable SIP.

Comment: For Homebrew and fish, the path is /opt/homebrew/bin/fish

Answer (score 64):

Funnily enough, the same method you link to in your question *still* works in OS X Lion through Sierra (10.12). The only difference: The preference pane is named *Users & Groups* instead of *Accounts*.

> 1. Open "System Preferences" → "Users & Groups".
> 2. Unless the lock icon is already unlocked, click the lock icon and authenticate yourself.
> 3. Context-click on a user in the list of user names
>      (hold down the <kbd>Control</kbd> key while clicking, or right-click on a right-handed two button mouse).
> 4. In context menu, choose "Advanced Options…".
> 5. Choose "Login shell" in the sheet that appears.
>
> The note at the top of the "Advanced Options" screen
>   claims you have to restart for the change to take effect,
>   but you really just need to log out and back in again.

[image]

Comment: ouhp. bummer. :|

Comment: Confirmed that this works in Mountain Lion, as well as working with "non-standard shells" that you might install yourself (or have Homebrew install).

Comment: Confirmed still working in 10.10 Yosemite.

Comment: right click on the username to bring up the menu containing "advanced options".  That took me a couple of minutes to find.

Comment: @pdwalker Right, I wrote this answer on the assumption that you read the question (and clicked the link there, which describes how to do this except for the name of the preference pane).

Comment: Why force someone to go offsite to gather all the information before being able to the answer?  Hence the comment in case someone else makes the same assumption that the answer is here rather than here and there.

Comment: Seems to be for an outdated version of OSX. El Capitan doesn't have the context menu.

Comment: @jvriesem Actually, it does. My guess is you skipped step 2.

Comment: @DanielBeck: Sure enough! Thanks! I would have expected that the context menu would show regardless of authenticated status, but then that window would have a lock at the bottom.

Comment: Confirmed still works in macOS 10.13 High Sierra

Comment: This still works in macOS 12 Monterey.

Answer (score 13):

Or:

```
sudo dscl . change /users/$USER UserShell /bin/bash $(which zsh)
```

Comment: Can you explain why this answers the question?

Comment: Be sure to run this *after* `brew install zsh`.

Comment: Also, be careful that the path of zsh installed via homebrew is different. I do it as: `sudo dscl . change /users/$USER UserShell /bin/bash $(which zsh)`

Comment: WARNING: This will break your shell if you copy / paste it without checking the path of zsh first. Do what metakermit said instead.

Answer (score 2):

An update, on Ventura, you can either use dscl as people have described above, or go into the system settings and control click (or right click) on your user name. You will then be able to choose advanced options and from there add your shell as the login shell. But be careful so that you do not break anything.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1161422)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wondering same problem happens on macOS Sierra and following command allowed me to change shell without problems:

```
chpass -s /usr/local/bin/zsh
```

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute. "chfn and chsh are synonyms for chpass."

Answer (score 0):

Running this

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/$USER UserShell /usr/local/bin/zsh
```

worked for me to fix

```
(eval):setopt:3: no such option: NO_warnnestedvar
```

which popped up everytime autocomplete should kick in

found in https://rick.cogley.info/post/use-homebrew-zsh-instead-of-the-osx-default/