# can't use my terminal after trying to update bash Mac OS

Tags: bash, terminal, shell

I was following a tutorial on how to update my bash version and everything was fine until I had to add `/usr/local/bin/bash` into `/etc/shells`. after I added it I had to run this command sudo `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash`. It gave me an error saying

```
/usr/local/bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

then I tried restarting my terminal then it said this

```
login: /usr/local/bin/bash: No such file or directory

[Process completed]
```

So then I went to the files that I edited via a text editor and changed them back to how the were before. But then after I restarted my terminal again I got the same error.

Comment: You should be able to change the shell back to either `/bin/bash` or `/bin/zsh` with Daniel Beck's answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/362372/how-to-change-the-login-shell-on-mac-os-x-from-bash-to-zsh/363555#363555) or Chopper3's similar answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/379725/how-do-i-change-a-users-default-shell-in-osx/379726#379726).

Comment: Which MacOS version? What tutorial - is it applicable to your MacOS version? In Mojave bash path is /bin/bash, /usr/local/bin doesn't have even symlink to bash.